# Time Zones in PHP, Date, MySQL...?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, timezone

I am trying to figure out how to display time in PST on my php site.
I have been putting in timestamps in the MySQL Database with NOW() and calling them like this:

date("m/d/y g:i a", strtotime($ref['lastupdated']))

However, the server time is in Central and However, as the website is geared towards people in the PST time zone. Basically it needs to show in PST. Is there a way I could do this - like, take that value and subtract 2 or something? Any ideas?

I'm not sure also if I need to go about this the PHP route or if the problem, rather, could be solved via MySQL.

Any ideas are appreciated - thanks!

```
$query = "SELECT refid, CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) refname, email, street, city, state, zip, interestlvl, status, added, lastupdated FROM referrals WHERE affid='$affid' ORDER BY added DESC;";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query Failed: ".mysql_errno()." - ".mysql_error()."<BR>\n$Query<BR>\n");


    if ($result) {
            while ($ref = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))      {
                echo '


    <td bgcolor="#EFEFEF" class="list">'.
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
        $date = new DateTime($ref['lastupdated']);
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
        $date->format('m/d/y g:i a')
        .'</td>';
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime($ref['lastupdated']);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $date->format('m/d/y g:i a');
```

given that *PST* is *America/Los Angeles*. You have to make sure that `date.timezone` is set to the correct timezone for *Central*. This can either be accomplished via the [`php.ini`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php) or via [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

The code then treats your incoming string `$ref['lastupdated']` as being in the default timezone (*Central*) and converts the date-time into the *America/Los_Angeles* timezone.

Comment: This works great, but sometimes I get the value returned like this: 102/04/11 11:56 am . There is an odd "1" appearing from no where. I've checked that it's not in the HTML. Any clue? Thank you!

Comment: 2011-02-04 13:56:44 is the value from MySQL.
Then I get 102/04/11 11:56 am from the code. :O
Even if I change it to like, M/d/y I get 1Feb/04/11

Comment: Please show all of the relevant code... I highly doubt that the snippet above produces this output.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the relevant code in the original thread, as the comment was formatting it weird!

Comment: I got it! I was putting an echo in an echo. I'm sorry for that! Thank you SO much!